# Spring boot JAVA - how to maintain user logging details and identify any API is not called for certain time interval specific to user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, angular5

We are using Angular5 as front-end. Spring Boot JAVA for APIs. We would like to maintain logged in/logged out details of users like, when a user say user1 logged in(field loggedin in table is set as 1), and after logout  (loggedin field value updating as 0).

This is working fine in normal scenario. In case, user closes the browser or closes the tab, at that time, API is not triggered so consequently, in table level also it is not updating.

Finally, we thought like, if no APIs are triggered for certain 5 minutes or certain time interval then we have planned to assume the user might logged out. So, we are trying to find out , like if no APIs are calling for last 5 minutes user-wise. How can we arrive it?

Actually, we are new to Spring Boot JAVA. Kindly guide us on this or any other idea or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using extra tags to track user activity, maybe you want to limit it to users current actions (like for logout, just update that logged out, as it would implicitly mean used not logged in anymore).

To achieve what you are looking, there is a session associated with every request, maybe new created or the existing one. You can keep a track of sessions created, and if any session is inactive for more than timeout time, you can destroy the session and while doing so, you can update the status of related tags at that step.

Comment: Hi Nithin,Thanks for the reply. Can you please explain more on this.How can we achieve user session in Spring Boot Java? Any Link or Sample codes are highly appreciated.

Comment: so there can be different approaches around this, one can use a separate scheduled thread to wipe off any timed out sessions from memory and at the same time, you can log that session was wiped off for inactivity. But, you would want to keep the work of this scheduled service to minimum required because you don't want it to eat up a lot of memory as it will run parallel to main app.